# HTML Forms and JS Backend

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am coding a site with HTML, CSS and JS and there is a form in the start which is supposed to ask for 2 things:- the user id and password. Like this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVnCF.png)

After that, on clicking submit, there is a `<div id="newform">new form here</div>` which should open on the page if the user id and the password both exist in lists such as the following:

```
    function versubmitted (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var username = document.getElementById("verifyuname").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("verifypw").value;    
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if (username === users[i]) {
            if ((password === pw[i])) {
              var finaluserid = username;
            } else {
              document.getElementById("verstatus").innerHTML = "The username is correct, but the password doesnt match!";
            }
          } else {
            document.getElementById("verstatus").innerHTML = "The username does not exist!";
            //Username doesnt exist
          }
        }
}
```

And further js like this:

```
var users = ["QWERTY", "DVORAK"];
var pw = ["abc", "ABC"];
var notverstat = false;

if (notverstat) {
  document.getElementById("newform").innerHTML = "Please login first!";
}
```

However, it doesn't check the user id and password correctly. I have added the onclick function. It doesnt show me the required output (it doesnt show the status message nor open the next form).

At the same time, I want the user id from the first form to be autofilled in the second form, but everytime it comes as the variable name instead of the string it is supposed to hold using the `.value` feature.

Also, is there a way to encrypt the arrays/lists so that a user cannot access it from the console? I do not want anyone accessing the user id and password list...

Thanks in advance!

edit: Here's the html for the form:

```
<div>
<form method="post">
    <label for="verifyuname">User ID</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="verifyuname" name="verifyname" placeholder="Login ID...">
<br>
    <label for="verifypw">Password</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="verifypw" name="pwver" placeholder="Your password..">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="versubmitted()">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="verstatus">
</div>

<div>
  <div id="verified">
  <div id="teststatus">
  <form method="post">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
<br>
    <label for="uname">Username</label>
    <br>
    <input readonly type="text" id="uname" name="username" value=finaluserid> (this is what i wanted to take autofilled as user id)
<br>
  
  <h3>Problem</h3>
    <p>Find the sum of all primes lesser than 10.</p>
<br>
    <input type="text" id="ans1" name="answer1" placeholder="Your answer...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitted()">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The teststatus div is for a timer for the test which I have initialized using this:

```
        <script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("May 10, 2021 13:58:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  if (days < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time's up!";   
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "-";   
    document.getElementById("teststatus").innerHTML = "Time's up, so the test automatically closed!"; 
  }

  else {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";      

  document.getElementById("timer2").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";    
  }
  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"


  // If the count down is finished, write some text
}, 1000);
</script>
```

I hope this suffices!

EDIT2: Can somebody help?

Comment: please store and verify user credentials in server-side (e.g.: php/node) instead on client-side. If the browser can read/decrypt those credentials, then some random attacker can also do it

Comment: I was thinking of using a .env file...

Comment: Also, can you help me figure out the other issues?

Comment: You haven't included any of the code that shows the HTML of your input fields and button.  Nor have you included the code where the "username" and "password" variables are set.  Whilst I certainly agree with @Kristian that implementation with usernames and passwords just included in arrays in the client-side JS is really not a good approach, if you want to understand why your current code is not working as you expect, you'll need to include more information in your question

Comment: Sure, let me add it!

Comment: I added the required code! Please help! @Craig

Comment: I still don't see anywhere in what you've posted where the "username" and "password" variables are being set ..... I'm guessing you need to add the code for your "versubmitted()" function?

Comment: fixed! can you check now... i think I've added everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix html code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="versubmitted(event)">
```